# How to properly use a class function to CustomSort a TStringList?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

In Delphi, I created a small class like this:

```
TFilesSorter = class
public
  constructor Create(ExtOrderList: TStrings);
  function SoryByExt(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
private
  ExtOrder: TStrings;
end;
```

I created a class because the `SoryByExt` function needs an ordered list of extensions (`ExtOrder`) used in the sort.

When I try to use my class function with `CustomSort`, like this:

```
FilesSorter := TFilesSorter.Create(ExtensionsList);
try
  SomeTStringList.CustomSort(FilesSorter.SoryByExt);
finally
  FilesSorter.Free;
end;
```

I get an error:

> E2009 Incompatible types: 'regular procedure and method pointer'

Now I understand why (it works only with a non-class function), but I'm wondering how to use `CustomSort` when you need another variable (my ordered list of extension used during the sort process) without using global variables? I want to separate the responsibilities and not have shared variables.

What is the proper way to do this (I use Delphi 11)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TStringList.CustomSort()` does not support non-static class methods for its sort routine. So, when using a *standard* `TStringList`, if you need to access an external variable from inside your sort routine then it would have to be a global variable. Or, since the sort routine does have access to the `TStringList` that is being sorted, you could store a pointer to the external variable in one of the entries of the `TStringList.Objects` property (if you are not using it for something else, that is).

Otherwise, an alternative option would be to derive a new class from `TStringList` and add whatever members you want to it, and then replace the original `TStringList` with your custom `TStringList`. That way, your sort routine can then typecast its `List` parameter to that derived class to access the extra members you added to it.

For example, in this case, `TFilesSorter` itself could be the new `TStringList` descendant, eg:

```
TFilesSorter = class(TStringList)
public
  constructor Create(ExtOrderList: TStrings);
  function SoryByExt(List: TStrings);
private
  ExtOrder: TStrings;
end;

constructor TFilesSorter.Create(ExtOrderList: TStrings);
begin
  inherited Create;
  ExtOrder := ExtOrderList;
end;

function doSoryByExt(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  // use TFilesSorter(List).ExtOrder to compare
  // List.Strings[Index1] with List.Strings[Index2]
  // as needed...
  Result := ...;
end;

function TFilesSorter.SoryByExt(List: TStrings);
begin
  Self.Assign(List);
  Self.CustomSort(doSoryByExt);
  List.Assign(Self);
end;

...

FilesSorter := TFilesSorter.Create(ExtensionsList);
try
  FilesSorter.SoryByExt(SomeTStringList);
finally
  FilesSorter.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I like the TStringList descendant idea but I guess I won't be able to use the CustomSort since I will have the same E2009 error?

Comment: The idea would be that you would replace the original `TStringList` with the new `TStringList`-derived class.  If that is not an option, you could just copy the strings from original list to the custom list, sort the custom list, and then copy the result back to the original list.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `CustomSort` accepts only a regular function as argument, not a class method.

You could solve it, and keep using `TStringList.CustomSort`, by using the fact that a Delphi  unit is also an encapsulation, that nicely hides away implementation details. You can view a unit's `interface` section as similar to a class's `public` section, and the unit's `implementation` section as similar to the class's `private` section. The unit's `initialization` and `finalization` sections are counterparts to the class's constructor and destructor.

There can of course exist only one instance of a unit, so this pattern corresponds to the singleton pattern with classes, where only exactly one object of the class is ever created.

Here is a possible solution to your problem:

```
unit FilesSorter;

interface

uses
  System.Classes;

procedure SetFilesSorterExtList(ExtOrderList: TStrings);
function SortByExt(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;


implementation

var
  FilesExtOrderList: TStringList;

procedure SetFilesSorterExtList(ExtOrderList: TStrings);
begin
  FilesExtOrderList.Clear;
  FilesExtOrderList.AddStrings(ExtOrderList);
end;

function SortByExt(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  // ... Implement comparison logic ...
end;

initialization
  FilesExtOrderList := TStringList.Create;
finalization
  FilesExtOrderList.Free;
end.
```